# Создание собственного Windows инсталлятора

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windowsinstaller

Большинство инсталляторов создаётся при помощи разных утилит (WiX, Inno Setup, Install Shield и т.д.). Меня интересует вопрос создания инсталлятора с собственным UI, как это сделано, например, у Kaspersky Anti-Virus и у Visual Studio.

Возможно ли использование .NET Framework в таких делах или потребуется чистый C++? Не будет ли ни у кого ссылок на пояснения того, что конкретно должен делать инсталлятор?

Comment: Если инсталятор предназначен для ОС на которых есть дотНет - то можно и писать на шарпе. Другое дело, версии дотнета из коробки везде разные, на вин7 к примеру по моему 3.5 по умолчанию. А делать инсталятор должен ровно то, что нужно разработчику. Копировать файлы, создавать ярлыки, писать в реестр.

Comment: Я так не пробовал, но возможно, вам нужно скомпилировать инсталлятор как msi-файл. В вашей программе запускать его в тихом режиме и перехватывать его вывод.

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/2335950/1988244 - там в ответе и комментах есть ссылки на примеры embedded ui. И еще где-то в стандартных примерах WIX есть пример с ui на WPF.

Comment: https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/tree/master/Source/src/WixSharp.Samples/Wix%23%20Samples/Custom_UI/EmbeddedUI_WPF

Comment: Умоляю, пожалуйста, не надо ещё одного велосипеда. Я весь этот долбанный зоопарк поддерживаю и я уже затрахался. Хочешь инсталлер - раскури тот, который на выходе отдаст валидный `msi`.

Comment: Вы действительно предлагаете создание некоторого велосипеда. Т.е. я могу написать свой UI, но при этом всё таки использовать WiX... Зачем мне это? Я бы хотел написать инсталлятор не используя готовые решения типо различных библиотек или других программ.

Answer (score 4):

Для создания кастомного UI через WIX можно использовать [Burn / BootstrapperApplication](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/authoring_bundle_application.html) - стандартный способ для создания оберток поверх MSI.

Пример для WPF есть в [src-пакете WiX](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/tag/wix3111rtm), в папке `src\Setup\WixBA`. Прикручивается (судя по документации) примерно так:

1. Собирается DLL с UI (WixBA из примеров)
2. В bundle.wxs (есть в стандартном шаблоне WiX для VS) добавляется

   ```
   <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
     <Payload SourceFile="$(var.InstallSourceResources)Bootstrapper\WixBA.dll"/>
     <Payload Id="FusionInstallUX.config"
          SourceFile="$(var.InstallSourceResources)Bootstrapper\WixBA.BootstrapperCore.config"
          Name="BootstrapperCore.config" Compressed="yes"/>
   </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
   ```

Сам по себе кастомный UI - это [просто класс-наследник `BootstrapperApplication`](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/Setup/WixBA/WixBA.cs)  в сборке, отмеченной атрибутом `BootstrapperApplicationAttribute`.

Пример конфига:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup
            name="wix.bootstrapper"
            type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperSectionGroup, BootstrapperCore">

            <section
                name="host"
                type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.HostSection, BootstrapperCore" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    </startup>

    <wix.bootstrapper>
        <host assemblyName="FusionInstallUX">
            <supportedFramework version="v4\Full" />
            <supportedFramework version="v4\Client" />
        </host>
    </wix.bootstrapper>
</configuration>
```

Более подробные примеры:

- [Custom WiX Burn bootstrapper user interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840380/custom-wix-burn-bootstrapper-user-interface)
- [Creating a custom UI installer with WIX Burn Bootstrapper](https://frozencloud.wordpress.com/2016/05/03/creating-a-custom-ui-installer-with-wix-burn-bootstrapper/)
- [Author Bootstrapper Application for a Bundle](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/authoring_bundle_application.html)

---

Альтернативный вариант без burn / .NET, который (в теории) можно прикрутить к любому msi-инсталлятору - прописывание EmbeddedUI DLL в таблице MsiEmbeddedUI. Базовый пример и требования к dll расписаны в [MSDN, Using an Embedded UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542588(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72451/discussion-on-answer-by-pashapash---windows-).

Answer (score 1):

Создавать инсталлятор полностью с нуля (без использования модели Windows Installer), только ради красивого интерфейса, наверное не стоит. Установить приложение легко, сложнее корректно его удалить во всех ситуациях, не оставив мусора и не запоров настройки системы - особенно если программа меняет ассоциации файлов, устанавливает свои расширения проводника, регистрирует COM-объекты и т.п.

Инсталлятор в Windows Installer состоит из двух частей:

- Файл *.MSI - это база данных, которая содержит информацию о структуре приложения, его файлы (либо информацию, где они лежат, если они не встроенные), перечень изменений в реестре и др. Его можно создавать с помощью стандартной утилиты *Orca.exe* из *Windows SDK* или с помощью какой-либо сторонней утилиты.
- Приложение-обертка (setup.exe), которое проверяет наличие необходимой версии Windows Installer, при необходимости предлагает пользователю ее установить, а затем запускает установку самой программы с помощью функции [MsiInstallProduct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370315(v=vs.85).aspx).

Они могут по разному между собой соотноситься (MSI внутри EXE, MSI в папке рядом с EXE, EXE скачивает MSI с интернета), но суть одинакова.

Приложение-обертка может использовать либо стандартный интерфейс Windows Installer, либо отключить его и зарегистрировать свой (вызовами `MsiSetInternalUI`/`MsiSetExternalUI` перед `MsiInstallProduct`). Можно использовать любую GUI-технологию для создания своего интерфейса, а затем передать параметры в MSI с помощью строки [свойств](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx) типа `TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files\MyApp" ADDLOCAL="Feature1, Feature2"`.

См. данные разделы документации:

[Общая документация по Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc185688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Windows Installer for Game Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee419048(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Windows Installer Development Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372834(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш ответ показался мне наиболее информативным, но у меня осталась ещё пара вопросов. Orca.exe позволяет как создавать так и редактировать MSI файлы? Имеются ли у вас полезные ссылки по работе с Orca.exe (перечень всех настроек создания MSI, например)?

Comment: Вообще, UI этой программы не выглядит дружелюбно)) Есть ли какие либо другие приложения по созданию MSI, которые имеют подобный функционал, но и дают описания какая настройка за что отвечает?

Comment: @D.Stark Orca - только редактирует. Чтобы создать новый инсталлятор, нужно взять за основу пустой шаблон uisample.msi из SDK, и в него заносить данные. Посмотрите вот этот пример: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367563(v=vs.85).aspx Описание таблиц БД можно посмотреть тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368259(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: "Вообще, UI этой программы не выглядит дружелюбно))" - ну да, утилиты типа Wix придумали не зря. Насчет более дружелюбных редакторов даже не знаю. Обычно достаточно Wix, а другие подобные приложения в основном платные.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте графические интерфейсы, такие как `GDI`, `GDI+`, `DirectDraw` если хотите инсталлятор со своим гуи. Для работы с файлами(распаковка и т.д.) Вам понадобятся такие WinApi функции как `CreateFile` `WriteFile` `ReadFile`. Файлы, которые Вы будете устанавливать могут быть как ресурсами exe'шника, так и отдельным файлом. Запись в реестр тоже через WinApi - `RegCreateKeyEx()` `RegOpenKeyEx()` `RegCloseKey()` `RegGetValue()` `RegSetValueEx()` `RegDeleteValue()`.

Comment: Вы меня несколько не так поняли. Я имел ввиду не как мне это сделать, а что мне нужно делать. Вопрос о том, что обычно делают инсталляторы. Вот, например, создам я инсталлятор при помощи Install Shield - это будет некоторый EXE-файл, который утилита собрала для меня учитывая те настройки, которые я задал. Что внутри этого EXE? Какие действия должна делать программа, чтобы считаться инсталлятором? Нужно же как то регистрировать программу в Windows - писать в нужные ветки реестра, указывать путь к деинсталлятору, имя программы и т.д., распаковывать файлы. Какие действия нужны?

Comment: @D.Stark Никакие действия не нужны. Инсталятор ничем принципиально не отличается от других программ.

Comment: @D.Stark, ну инсталлятор это по-сути архиватор: у вас есть сжатые(не обязательно) файлы программы, и Вам их надо распаковать в ProgramFiles\MyProg, например. Храниться эти файлы могут либо в ехешнике(как ресурсы), который Вы соберёте,  либо, в виде отдельного файла. Ничего регистрировать не надо, это обычная программа.

Comment: `Ничего регистрировать не надо` — надо деинсталлятор зарегистрировать в `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

Comment: Вопрос же вполне конкретный - как сделать кастомный интерфейс для msi. Ответ "работайте с графикой через при для графики и с файлами - через при для файлов" к нему почти никакого отношения не имеет. И нет,  msi это не просто архиватор.

Comment: @VTT инсталлятор msi - отличается. Как минимум способом прикручивания интерфейса к готовой системе установки файлов.

Comment: @PashaPash При чем тут msi?

Comment: @vtt на вопросе соответствующий тег стоит. И в самом вопросе - перечислены утилиты для создания msi.

Comment: @PashaPash WiX там упоминается только среди прочих. В любом случае, инсталятор можно делать совсем без msi.

Comment: @vtt можно. Но гораздо проще взять стандартный механизм инсталляции,  готовый тулсет под него (WIX) и прикрутиить только кастомный UI (как сделано в тех примерах,  которые перечислил топикастер) ,  чем делать полный велосипед.

Comment: @PashaPash, человек как раз и спрашивал из чего велосипед состоит, и как работает. Я Ему это и объяснил. Создавать деинсталлятор - это по желанию, прямого отношения к тому, по какому принципу работает инсталлятор он не имеет.

Comment: Человек хотел инсталлятор,  а не конкретно "полностью самописный инсталлятор-велосипед". Перечислил конкретные примеры не-велосипедов (все примеры из вопроса сделаны на основе msi). Вы ему объяснили как сделать велосипед, причем на уровне "велосипеды делаются из колес,  рамы и руля". Да,  полностью корректный ответ. В стиле "для написания приложения под Windows используйте WinAPI". И полностью бесполезный в практическом смысле, т.к. не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме из вопроса.

Comment: Т.е. смотрите - на вопросе стоит тег C#. Значит можно запостить ответ "для создания инсталлятора нужно написать код на c# который поставит файлы и поправит реестр"? Да,  будет ответом.  Но пользы от такого ответа - никакой.

Comment: @PashaPash Вы правы. Мне не нужно использовать готовые решения.

Comment: @PashaPash, Вы же видите что человек как раз пытался разобраться в начинке. Его интересовало написание "с нуля" не используя WIX и всё что Вы перечислили.  А мой ответ был абсолютно полезным, а не так как Вы написали, т.к. я описал основной алгоритм и перечислил почти все  нужные функции. Куда конкретней? Программу полностью написать?) Хотя о полезности решать не Вам и не мне а автору вопроса.

Comment: @АртурКлочко ну ок, теперь человек знает что инсталлятор должен копировать файлы и создавать записи в реестре. Надеюсь, ему это окажется очень полезным :)

Comment: @PashaPash, конечно окажется) Как раз это Он и спрашивал  -  "Вопрос о том, что обычно делают инсталляторы."

Answer (score 0):

У нас используется NSIS (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). Достаточно просто и удобно.

Одним из основных требований к инсталлятору является минимизация всех внешних зависимостей (таких как дотнет или прочие библиотеки) и высокая отказоустойчивость.

Так же можно посмотреть в сторону самораспаковывающихся архивовю